# How can I modify the SVG's viewBox while using dvisvgm

Tags: svg, shapes, dvisvgm

I have been converting tex files into svg:

```
lualatex --output-format=dvi flowchart.tex
dvisvgm flowchart.dvi
```

but the SVG's attributes always holds a view box with min-x, min-y value of

```
viewBox='-72.0023 -72.0023 ...'
```

I would like to set the min-x, min-y to 0,0 **before generating the shapes** on the canvas.

I have read the man of dvisvgm, which some of it was unclear for me,
Can someone please assist me?

Comment: You can use option `--translate` (or `-t`) to move the graphics to a different location, e.g. `dvisvgm -t72.0023,72.0023 flowchart.dvi`. What do you mean by setting the minimum coordinates "before generating the shapes"?

Comment: @Martin thank you for your kind answer, I'll explain:
When I draw a simple circle shape with tex: "\tikz \draw (15,15) circle [radius=30pt];"
I get <svg height='60.174pt' version='1.1' viewBox='-71.997 -72.005 60.177 60.174' width='60.177pt'> in the svg. how come the viewBox is not set '0 0 60.177 60.174'?
For some reason the translate feature did not work for me on the dvi file I tried few times, I'm using dvisvgm 2.1.3 .

Comment: According to the DVI specification, origin (0,0) is located 1 inch away from the top and left paper edge, i.e. (-1in,-1in) denotes the top left corner of the output canvas. If the circle is drawn without any margins directly at the top left corner of the page, you get the mentioned coordinates. dvisvgm option `--translate=1in,1in` should move the contents to (0,0). If it doesn't, there's probably a bug in dvisvgm 2.1.3. Since that version is pretty old, you should consider updating it to the latest release 2.10.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it!